# Salesforce1 Push Notifications Implementation

Tags: salesforce1-app, push-notification

I am implementing this feature of customized push notifications on Salesforce1. I cannot find any useful information on the Internet and I need help.

So here it is, how can I send a push notification to a Salesforce1 app?

I already know how to turn the feature on from Setup, but I need to know how exactly to implement it. Do I need to use process builder? or Apex Code? If Apex Code is needed, what exact class or methods should I use?

i found a method called "Messaging.PushNotification()" from a guide and I tried to use it. It invokes a "Messaging.send()" method to send the notification to the app. However, it needs two arguments, one is the userid of the target user, the other one is the "API name" of the connected app. Does anyone knows what is the API name of Salesforce1 app?

I am testing on an Android phone. However if anyone knows the methods for IOS it will also be helpful.

Thank you! I am really frustrated to be blocked by this simple feature two whole days.